# print out female students only from the array

Tags: java, arrays

How do i print out female only students from an array. My current code prints out all students. the gender variable is boolean (male = true, female = false).

```
public class SMSMain {
    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Student student[] = new Student[3]; 
// Create an instance of student object
//set different attributes of the individual student.  
student[0] = new Student();  
student[0].setNewId(10);  
student[0].setName("Maria");
student[0].setGender(female);
student[1] = new Student();  
student[1].setNewId(11);  
student[1].setName("Mark");
student[1].setGender(male);
student[2] = new Student();  
student[2].setNewId(12);  
student[2].setName("Denise");
student[2].setGender(female);



System.out.println("\n\nFemale students are:");  
for(int i=0; i < student.length; i++){ 

System.out.println( "Student " + (i+1) + " Name :: " + student[i].getName() + ", Student ID :: " + student[i].getIdNumber());
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the `if` statement?

Comment: What about some `if( !student[i].getGender())` check? Btw, that name is really misleading, you might change that to either use an enum or the name to be `setMale(...)` and `isMale()`.

Comment: Obviously, females are not a gender.

Comment: @Max let's hope no females read that ... ;)

Comment: @Max obviously, males don't have brains - hach, qed again :-)  Thomas hope you may ... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like the following would work

```
System.out.println("\n\nFemale students are:");  
for(int i=0; i < student.length; i++){ 
    if (student[i].getGender() == false) {
       System.out.println( "Student " + (i+1) + " Name :: " + student[i].getName() + ", Student ID :: " + student[i].getIdNumber());
    }
}
```

This code runs through every object in the array, checking whether the value returned by getGender is set to false (aka female). If this condition is true, the print statement is executed.

btw, as pointed out by other posters, the use of the name Gender is quite misleading here, a method like `isMale()` and `isFemale()` that would return boolean based on the gender of the person would be a better solution.

Comment: (1) don't feed answers. (2) Without explanation - he's not likely to learn anything from just a code

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i < student.length; i++){
  if(!student[i].getGender()) {
     // do ur thing
  }
}
```

Use `if` condition to check whether the student is female

Comment: (1) don't feed answers. (2) Without explanation - he's not likely to learn anything from just a code

Answer (score 2):

A slightly cleaned up version.

- stored the actual student in a local variable
- checked for `null` students to avoid null pointer exceptions
- used the printf method
- added one extra method

.

```
for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
  Student student = student[i];
  if (student != null && isFemale(student)) {
    System.out.printf("Student %s Name :: %s, Student ID :: %s%n", 
                            i+1, student.getName(), student.getId());
  }
}
```

this uses the method

```
private boolean isFemale(Student student) {
  return (student.getGender() == false);
}
```

(I quickly invented the method because no-one really understands that women don't have a gender ;) )

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
for (Student stud: student) {
  if (!stud.getGender()) {
     System.out.println(stud.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: That would print all *male* students.

Comment: corrected that. but i think it doesn't really matter which gender to print. i mean i wanted to show the idea.